# telegram buttons below text c#

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

there are button below telegram text in bot how can i do it to?
this is the max info that i can give about this cuz i dont know what is it called or somthing.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jscmg.png)

```
var new_keyboard = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(
            new[]
                 {
                  new[]
                     {
                      new InlineKeyboardButton("step_1","step1") ,
                      },
                  new[]
                      {
                      new InlineKeyboardButton("step_2","step2"),
                      new InlineKeyboardButton("step_3","step3"),
                       },
                  new[]
                       {
                      new InlineKeyboardButton("step_4","step4"),
                       }
              });
api.EditMessageReplyMarkupAsync(chatid, messageid, replyMarkup: new_keyboard);
```

Answer (score 0):

The buttons below text message called `InlineKeyboardMarkup`, You can pass it with `SendTextMessageAsync` method, Or by default it's null, like this:

```
private void bot_OnMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs msg)
{
    // Defining InlineKeyboardButtons
    List<List<InlineKeybordButton>> buttons = new List<List<InlineKeybordButton>>(/*Two button lines!*/2);

    // Defining Rows (As List of buttons)
    List<InlineKeybordButton> row1 = new List<InlineKeybordButton>(/*One button in first row!*/1);
    List<InlineKeybordButton> row2 = new List<InlineKeybordButton>(/*One button in second row!*/1);
    
    // Adding buttons to the rows:
    row1.Add(InlineKeyboardButton.WithUrl("Google", "https://www.google.com/"));
    row2.Add(InlineKeyboardButton.WithUrl("Bing", "https://www.bing.com/"));


    // Adding rows to the list:
    buttons.Add(row1);        
    buttons.Add(row2);
    
    // HERE:
    // Inline Keyboard
    InlineKeyboardMarkup keyboard = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons);
    bot.SendTextMessageAsync(msg.Chat, "Some text...", replyMarkup: keyborad);
}
```